# Arrow without arr

Tags: haskell, arrows, category-theory

If we restrict our understanding of a category to be the usual `Category` class in Haskell:

```
class Category c where
  id :: c x x
  (>>>) :: c x y -> c y z -> c x z
```

Then let's say that an `Arrow` is a `Category` which can additionally:

```
class Category c => Arrow c where
  (***) :: c x y -> c x' y' -> c (x,x') (y,y')
  (&&&) :: c x y -> c x y' -> c x (y,y')
```

We can easily derive:

```
first :: c x y -> c (x,z) (y,z)
first a = a *** id

second :: c x y -> c (z,x) (z,y)
second a = id *** a
```

Or we can derive `(***)` from `first` and `second`:

```
a1 *** a2 = first a1 >>> second a2
```

We can also derive:

```
dup :: c x (x,x)
dup = id &&& id
```

Or we can derive `(&&&)` given `dup` and `(***)`:

```
a1 &&& a2 = dup >>> (a1 *** a2)
```

---

What's my point and what's my question? It's this:

What is `Arrow` without `arr`? It seems perfectly coherent and useful. Are there any arrow laws (aside from just category laws) that don't involve `arr` and remain intact here? And what does this all mean in category theory?

---

I basically stole this question from reddit, but generalized and expounded on it:
http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2e0ane/category_with_fanout_and_split_but_not_an_arrow/

Comment: I have that class in [my constrained-categories project](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/blob/master/Control/Arrow/Constrained.hs#L84), somewhat stupidly called `Morphism`. Some laws continue to make sense, even with no functions around... stuff like `fst` or `const` are methods of other classes in that package, and would need to be used to properly formulate the laws. I would be surprised if Edward, Conal or somebody hadn't already done that somewhere, but by which name I do not know...

Comment: You may want to read about [Generalized Arrows](http://www.megacz.com/berkeley/garrows/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as `Arrow` is a category with product, `Arrow` without `arr` is also a category with product (thus the category laws always hold).

`arr` is a functor from Hask category to `c` category. The code shown below indicates this. `arr` provides a way to lift normal functions (that are morphisms in Hask) into the instantiated `c` category. This is somewhat like `fmap` (endofunctor from Hask to Hask) but more generalized. Relating to this, some of the arrow laws [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html#g:1) describe the functor laws (though there are also the laws for product).

So by omitting `arr`, you lose the function to lift normal functions, or, from another point of view, get free from implementing it. However, all other characteristics are the same.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, RankNTypes #-}

-- | Functor arrow
type (:->) c d = forall a b. c a b -> d a b

-- | Hask category; types are objects, functions are morphisms.
type Hask = (->)

arr :: Arrow c => Hask :-> c
arr = Control.Arrow.arr
```